# Adjusting separation between matrix entries

Tags: spacing, matrices

I have a very large matrix which overflows in the margin. I would like the matrix to fit inside the margins, but I would like to do this without rescaling it, and also without affecting other array-type entries. Is it possible to adjust the horizontal separation between the matrix columns for one object?

I have tried doing the following:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation} 
A  = \setlength\arraycolsep{2pt}
\pmatrix{ A & B & \dots & C & D & E & \dots & F \cr
A & B & \dots & C & D & E & \dots & F \cr
A & B & \dots & C & D & E & \dots & F \cr
A & B & \dots & C & D & E & \dots & F \cr}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

but changing `\setlength\arraycolsep{2pt}` does not actually change the spacing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here I use a TABstack.  The intercolumn gap is settable, here to 2pt.  The interrow baselineskip may also be set with `\setstackgap{L}{<length>}`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\setstackEOL{\cr}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation} 
\setstacktabbedgap{2pt}
A  = \parenMatrixstack{
A & B & \dots & C & D & E & \dots & F \cr
A & B & \dots & C & D & E & \dots & F \cr
A & B & \dots & C & D & E & \dots & F \cr
A & B & \dots & C & D & E & \dots & F
}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 38):

The `\pmatrix` command you're using is foreign to LaTeX and it's directly imported from plain TeX, so it doesn't use the general framework of LaTeX arrays.

You should load the `amsmath` that provides the `pmatrix` *environment*, which uses the general framework.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
A  =
\begingroup % keep the change local
\setlength\arraycolsep{2pt}
\begin{pmatrix}
A & B & \dots & C & D & E & \dots & F \\
A & B & \dots & C & D & E & \dots & F \\
A & B & \dots & C & D & E & \dots & F \\
A & B & \dots & C & D & E & \dots & F
\end{pmatrix}
\endgroup
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

The `\begingroup`–`\endgroup` pair is not actually necessary if the “reduced” matrix is the only one in the `equation` environment, because the setting to `\arraycolsep` will disappear anyway at the end of the environment, but it does no harm either.

[image]

Comment: thank you for your answer. If this is not pushing it too far, is there a way to do this without the `amsmath` package? I cannot use it since it conflicts with the journal style I am using.

Answer (score 5):

At first, I propose to use the newer environment pmatrix, instead of `\pmatrix{}`. The etoolbox package can give you a solution:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{pmatrix}{\setlength{\arraycolsep}{20pt}}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation} 
\begin{pmatrix} A & B & \dots & C & D & E & \dots & F \cr
A & B & \dots & C & D & E & \dots & F \cr
A & B & \dots & C & D & E & \dots & F \cr
A & B & \dots & C & D & E & \dots & F \cr
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please post a compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/5001) rather than just a code snippet. Incidentally, setting `\arraycolsep` to `20pt` seems a tad excessive, given that (a) the default value of this parameter is `5pt` and (b) the OP has stated that the matrix is currently sticking out into the margins; quadrupling the amount of inter-column whitespace does not seem to be the way to go in this situation, does it? Did you maybe mean to set the parameter to `2pt`?

Comment: I meant `2pt` of course, as OP wanted, thank you for mentioning. "0" lies right above "p" on the keyboard...

Comment: This changes *all* `pmatrix` environments.

Comment: @Theo, thank you for your answer, but as I said in the question, I do not want to change the spacing in all matrices in the document, rather in just one of them.